# Prevent Excel from changing x-axis on a dynamic chart

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts

I wanted to make a dynamic chart that plots out the graph of a standard curve for a bio assay we perform frequently. Often to boost the fit of the curve you may drop one or two data points on either end of the data set. So using vlookups and if statements I have a scheme that performs that data trimming, such that my data always starts in Row 1 and the column length simply shortens.

My table works great, but my xy scatter chart goes bananas on these changes. I have the plot on a log log scale, which looks fine if the full data set is present. I lose the x axis detail when I perform a trim. The x- axis then resets to range of 1 to length of my data set.

How can I prevent this?

***UPDATE***

I added some information. I know there are VBA ways to do this but I would prefer to keep the spreadsheet as simple as possible. I would think excel should be able to handle this.

[image: This is the chart with all the points in it. The actual data driving it is cricled]

So if I have a bad fit I may want to trim the data series either from the beginning or end of the data set. I accomplish that with the spinner buttons to dynamically change the table but the following happens

[image: I essentially shorten the data by one and the chart goes haywire. I lose the log scale and any information about my x values]

My formula that updates the columns looks like the following. Its messy.

=IF(ISNA(IF(VLOOKUP(F6,$C$4:$D$11,2,FALSE)+1>8-($B$5-1),"",INDEX(C$4:C$11,VLOOKUP(F6,$C$4:$D$11,2,FALSE)+1))),"",IF(VLOOKUP(F6,$C$4:$D$11,2,FALSE)+1>8-($B$5-1),"",INDEX(C$4:C$11,VLOOKUP(F6,$C$4:$D$11,2,FALSE)+1)))

Comment: Can you show some sample data and a sample plot? Is log log on X axis or Y? And are you trimming from both ends or just the last data point? Can you use a dynamic named range for your axis and some code to set the axis as you want?

Comment: @QHarr I just uploaded some snap shots of the issue. Hopefully you could help.

Comment: The `y=16`-etc is raised to a negative power in the lower-most screencap. Is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: @Vegard That negative exponent is incorrect but that is the power fit generated by excel. The correct values would be the b and a coefficients (cells in the rightmost column) calculated above. I think it is a byproduct of the issue I am talking about where my x values disappear and are replaced by 1,2,3,etc... Hence the bounty. Thanks for taking a look at my problem.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @The TTG Guy I am using excel 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the formulas use `NA()` instead of `""`. Filling cell with `""` does not result in a true empty cell and is the reason why you are experiencing issues with your chart.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing the obvious here, but just hard-code the graph with a range of your choosing. In the sample screenshot, making the graph auto defaults the max range to 100,000. I went in and hard-coded the maximum to 50,000 (circled). Afterwards, the 5th data point is not displayed in the chart. Doesn't matter what the data shows at this point.[image]

Comment: I actually lose information about my x values. It converts my data to just 1,2,3.... So this wont work. I updated my post with more info. Hopefully you can help.

Comment: Hello - sorry, i don't think i can help, other to point out that clearly the spinner buttons are breaking something. from your screenshots, your data is sliding up in such a fashion that it is not representative of the other data in the rows. i don't think this is a problem with that ugly formula, not sure. I just have never used spinner buttons. good luck. i'd recommend to not use them. /2cents

Comment: Thanks for the help. The formula is ugly but it works the problem is link between the table and chart. It shouldn't break but it does.

Comment: As soon as any of the X values are non-numeric, ALL X values are treated as counting numbers 1, 2, 3, etc., in order of their appearance in the worksheet, ignoring the numeric appearance of the values. I wonder if your scary looking formula does this.